# Why JS functions are called only once in Karate framework if should several times?

Tags: function, karate

Here is my test scenario

```
Scenario:  build json using js function
* def x = read('classpath:data/user.json')
* def body = { updated : [], deleted : [] };
* def fun =
"""
 function(n){
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        x.email = 'api.test+' +  Math.random() + '@cii.io';
        body.updated.add(x);

    }
  }
"""
* eval fun(3)
* copy body = body
* print body
```

My expectations are that I will have 3 entities with 3 unique emails cause Math.random() is called each time.
But I see next in result

```
  {
   "updated": [
    {
      "email": "api.test+0.5327150054220268@cii.io",
      "businessUnit": "DE"
    },
    {
      "email": "api.test+0.5327150054220268@cii.io",
      "businessUnit": "DE"
    },
    {
      "email": "api.test+0.5327150054220268@cii.io",
      "businessUnit": "DE"
    }
  ],
  "deleted": [
  ]
}
```

I wondering what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
* def tmp = []
* def fun = function(n){ for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) tmp.add(i) }
* eval fun(3)
* print tmp
```

Comment: You are right, again))

The thing I cannot understand is better presented on these example: 
https://gist.github.com/kasheylm/ec7c3792045b265b8db6af8a2095c82e/revisions

 1. So changing one character from "tmp.add(**i**);" to "tmp.add(**x**);" breaks everything 
 2. To avoid this was used "copy body = body", but looks like Karate method "copy" calls JS function only once or adds last element N times.

Comment: @Denis as you already know - we will introduce an easier loop in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/735 - in general we recommend using Java code when your helper functions get complex, easier to debug and understand

Comment: Yep, you're right. And frankly, I undersood this after posting the question)